# In Kibana, how to show two different metrics(e.g. mean and count), in the same row?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

In kibana, we can create 'terms' panel type to show metrics like count or mean by setting appropriate terms_stats. But, in one row, we can see only one metrics, e.g. either mean or count.

I'm interested in means, with some minimum count. For this, either I would like to

A) show both count and mean in the same row.

B) set a filter on minimum count, then just show mean.

I am not able to find solution to any of the above. Kindly let me know if somebody solved this problem.

[PS: I'm using Kibana 3]